# Covert Pandas Series of text into list of words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that for each row a text review is present:
[image: series example]

I would like to convert this series into a unique list containing each word present in each review, for example:

s = [['the', 'pizza', 'was', 'okay'...], ['i', 'love', 'this', 'place', 'my', 'fiance', 'and', 'i', 'go'...]]

Expected output:

s = ['the', 'pizza', 'was', 'okay'..., 'i', 'love', 'this', 'place', 'my', 'fiance', 'and', 'i', 'go'...]

I have tried using `tolist()` and doing some loops but I am definitely missing something. What could be a good approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flattening:

```
out = [y for x in df['tokens'] for y in x]
```

Or use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from  itertools import chain
out = list(chain.from_iterable(df['tokens']))
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
L = list('abcdefghijklmno')

df = (pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'B':np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})
      .groupby('B')['A'].apply(list).to_frame('tokens'))
print (df)

In [269]: %timeit df['tokens'].sum()
15.1 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [270]: %timeit out = [y for x in df['tokens'] for y in x]
360 µs ± 15.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [271]: %timeit out = list(chain.from_iterable(df['tokens']))
215 µs ± 1.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem for this is that each letter is being split, but in my case, I want to keep each word as an element of the list.

Comment: @sanna - So need `out = [y for x in df['tokens'] for y in x.strip('[]').split(',')]` ?

Comment: @sanna - Added timings, `sum` is maybe nice, but slow, but it is up to you what solution is accepting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
df['tokens'].sum()
```

As it will *add up* all the lists.

Comment: Rather not, really slow.